# Find sum of quartic function coefficients by its plot

Tags: algebra-precalculus

the plot of quartic function $y=ax^4-x^2+bx+c$ is given:
[image: the plot]

I need to find a sum of $$\frac{a}{|a|} + 2\frac{b}{|b|} + 4\frac{c}{|c|} $$

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the plot get the values of $y$ at three different values of $x$, may be at $x\approx -1.5, -0.3$(where it appears to be $0$) and may be at $x=0$. You'll get three linear equations involving $a,b,c$. Solve them and you will get $a,b,c$ and can find the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\dfrac{x}{|x|}=\operatorname{sgn}(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{for }x\gt0\\-1&\text{for }x\lt0\end{cases}.$$

Look at how the function grows, that should give you an idea about the sign of $a$. Look at the point where the graph of your function crosses the $y$-axis, that should lead you to the sign of $c$.

Comment: And the gradient of the curve at x=0 is positive, which should tell you about the sign of b.

Answer (score 0):

I see that one of the roots is $-0.3$. So $y(-0.3) = 0$ is one of the equations. In $-1$ there is a local minimum, so you should have $y'(-1) = 0$. And I guess in $0.5$ the function becomes convex from not being such, so $y''(0.5) = 0$. These $3$ equations should be enough.